# Why does my $(x_1,y_1)$ have to be the focus and $(x_2,y_2)$ have to be a random point on a parabola.

Tags: conic-sections

I'm trying to write an equation for a parabola using the distance formula. My textbook shows this: 
[image: Part 1]

[image: Part 2]

[image: Part 3]

Why can't my distance from the focus be this: 
[image]

And why can't my distance from the directrix be this:
[image]

This doesn't seem like a wrong move to me but I clearly got the wrong answer. 
Is it possible to get the right answer using the equations I purposed?

Thank you in advance! please ask for any clarifying questions.

Comment: It can be; $(a-b)^2=(b-a)^2$.

Comment: I'm confused. What does that have to do with the distance formula and parabolas?

Comment: You were asking why the distance from the focus can't be $\sqrt{(1-x)^2+(-4-y)^2}$, but you can because that is equal to $\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y+4)^2}$

Comment: Oh, I see! And the rule (a-b)^2 = (b-a)^2 can be applied to  √(2-x)^2 right?

Comment: Please take the time to enter important parts of your question as text instead of pasting pictures of it. Your question should be comprehensible with images disabled, which this is certainly not. Also, images are neither searchable nor accessible to screen readers, nor do they show up in summaries. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/265466) you can find a quick reference for MathJax, which is used for formatting mathematical expressions on MSE.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a point $A(a,b)$ and a point $B(c,d)$ and draw the parrallel line to the $x$-axis and $y$-axis.
[image]

What is the lenght of $EB$ and $AE$? By the definition of the lenght of a segment parallel to the coordinates axis, we have: $$EB = |c - a|=|a-c|$$ and $$AE=|d-b|=|b-d|$$
We have also that $AEB = 90°$ and so by the Pythagorean theorem: $$AB=\sqrt{EB^2+AE^2}=\sqrt{|c - a|^2+|d-b|^2}=\sqrt{(c - a)^2+(d-b)^2}$$